# Sending tweets in background of application

Tags: java, android, social-networking, tweets

I've searched out over internet. I found many solution in order to send tweets and I got that using intent it's much better.

```
String tweetUrl = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=PUT TEXT HERE &url="+ "https://www.google.com";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(tweetUrl);
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

But I just want to send tweets in background. If anybody have done this ever please share with me. my requirement is to send tweets in background when a post is posted into my social networking based application. I am able to do it in case of facebook but still struggling with Twitter.

Here below is my code to take authentication for Twitter Application:-

```
class twAsyn extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         askOAuth();
        return null;  
    }

}

private void checkForSavedLogin() {  
     // Get Access Token and persist it  
     new accessUser().execute();
}  

class accessUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         AccessToken a = getAccessToken();  

            // storeAccessToken(a);
             loggedIUser.setTwSharing(true);
             if (a!=null) {

             // initialize Twitter4J  
             twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();  
             twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);  
             twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);  
             ((TwitterApplication)getApplication()).setTwitter(twitter);  
             final User user;
             finish(); 
              }
        return null;
    }

}

private AccessToken getAccessToken() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String token = settings.getString("accessTokenToken", "");
    String tokenSecret = settings.getString("accessTokenSecret", "");
    if (token!=null && tokenSecret!=null && !"".equals(tokenSecret) && !"".equals(token)){
        return new AccessToken(token, tokenSecret);
    }
    return null;
}

private void getConsumerProvider() {
    OAuthProvider p = ((TwitterApplication)getApplication()).getProvider();
    if (p!=null){
        provider = p;
    }
    CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer c = ((TwitterApplication)getApplication()).getConsumer();
    if (c!=null){
        consumer = c;
    }
}



private void setConsumerProvider() {
    if (provider!=null){
        ((TwitterApplication)getApplication()).setProvider(provider);
    }
    if (consumer!=null){
        ((TwitterApplication)getApplication()).setConsumer(consumer);
    }
}


private void storeAccessToken(AccessToken a) {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("accessTokenToken", a.getToken());
    editor.putString("accessTokenSecret", a.getTokenSecret());
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    System.out.println("RESUMING!!");
    if (this.getIntent()!=null && this.getIntent().getData()!=null){
        Uri uri = this.getIntent().getData();
        new twUserAcces(uri).execute();
    }
}

class twUserAcces extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    Uri uri;
    String verifier;
    public twUserAcces(Uri uri) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.uri = uri;
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(CALLBACK_URL)) {
            verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(oauth.signpost.OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        checkForSavedLogin();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {


            // this will populate token and token_secret in consumer
            provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, verifier);

            // Get Access Token and persist it

            System.out.println(">>>>>>>> accesstoker "+consumer.getToken());
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>> accesstoker "+consumer.getTokenSecret());
            AccessToken a = new AccessToken(consumer.getToken(), consumer.getTokenSecret());
            storeAccessToken(a);

            // initialize Twitter4J
            twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
            twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
            twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);
            ((TwitterApplication)getApplication()).setTwitter(twitter);
            Log.e("Login>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.", "Twitter Initialised");


            User user = null;
            long h=twitter.getId();
            user = (User)twitter.getUserLists(0);

            finish();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Log.e(APP, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("e.getMessage()=="+e.getMessage());
            //Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return null;
    }

}

private void askOAuth() {
    try {


        consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
        provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider("https://twitter.com/oauth/request_token", "https://twitter.com/oauth/access_token", "https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize");
        String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, CALLBACK_URL);
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Please authorize this app!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setConsumerProvider();
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to create an application and access token in this application. If you want to send some tweets to your account, you need to use update_status.json with application id, secret, and one access token. You can make your tests here https://apigee.com/console/twitter . Also refer here for sending tweet by using java http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html#updatingStatus

Answer (score 0):

For sending tweet in java, you can use [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html)

**Create a Twitter application:** Refer [here](http://iag.me/socialmedia/how-to-create-a-twitter-app-in-8-easy-steps/)

**Initialize your object:** Fill in credentials by using twitter app credentials

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
  .setOAuthConsumerKey("")
  .setOAuthConsumerSecret("")
  .setOAuthAccessToken("")
  .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("");
TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
```

**Send your tweet**

```
Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
Status status = twitter.updateStatus(latestStatus);
```

For best practices, please refer [here](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html#updatingStatus)

Comment: i tried with the same But it keeps responding with an Error. "Authentication credentials are missing"

Comment: Have you created your twitter app? Be sure that you have created access token also. And permission model must be read,write

Comment: Please check my edit answer. I pasted my Twitter authentication code. May be it will help for better understanding. I am using TwitterApplication Class as well.

Comment: Could you please debug your code inorder to get your credentials? You can log them. Your credentials are wrong. First watch it from log and compare them with twitter app settings

Comment: Yes, it's different. But how can i control this while i am using Right     CONSUMER_KEY & CONSUMER_SECRET.

Comment: Here is my code to access Consumer object then i get the Tokens from this object:----consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
   provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider("https://twitter.com/oauth/request_token", "https://twitter.com/oauth/access_token", "https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize");

Comment: But access token and access token doesnt change often. You need to get all credentials from your twitter app settings on app page, and paste them to your twitter4j factory as I mentioned above in my answer

Comment: Are you sure...it will never changed even its logout and login again. Should it be always a Fixed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45198/discussion-between-cubuzoa-and-suresh-sharma)